# Error in write Array in Raster file: ""ValueError: expected array of dim 2""

Tags: python, gdal, raster-conversion

I'm using Python in my research and how I don't have large experience in this language, I need Help to understand this error that occur when I`ll write a array as raster file.

```
data_res_b1_corrected = [np.zeros((col1, row1), np.float32)]

data_res_b1_corrected = (data_res_b1 - (coef_red_nir * (subt_nir_nir_med)))
print(data_res_b1_corrected.shape)
output1 = res_b1.GetDriver().Create('D:/CESAR_PHD/10.Lyzenga/output/Reservoir_RED_corrected.tif', col1, row1, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
output1.SetGeoTransform(geoT)
output1.SetProjection(proj.ExportToWkt())
output1.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data_res_b1_corrected)
output1.FlushCache()
```

The error occur when I`ll run this line:  "output1.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data_res_b1_corrected)"

The console returns: ValueError: expected array of dim 2

Comment: Sounds like your numpy Array have more dimension than 2. What is Printing with `print(data_res_b1_corrected.shape)`?

Comment: print(data_res_b1_corrected.shape)
(1, 8619, 5975)

Comment: Try changing first line to `data_res_b1_corrected = np.array(np.zeros((col1, row1), np.float32))` otherwise you are creating a list

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: It is difficult to help when your code is not reproceable. For example what is col1, row1, coef_red_nir subt_nir_nir_med and data_res_b1? What is the shape of data_res_b1?

Comment: col1 and row1 are variable containing the the value from pixel from original image in X and Y. (data_res_b1 - (coef_red_nir * (subt_nir_nir_med))) is an expression to corrected the values from array in data_res_b1. The result from this expression will be added on array data_res_b1_corrected. I want generate the raster file containing the values into data_res_b1_corrected.

Comment: You need to check [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564495/what-does-numpy-ndarray-shape-do) for each of your calculation steps. The error is telling you it should be 2D, for example (8619, 5975)

Comment: Ok...I'll check the shape from all calculation steps. Thank you for help me!!

Comment: @BERA Does Python have an inbuilt raster dataset for creating reproducible examples?